# multidimensional array, comparing the values

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, multidimensional-array

I got this inside my twig template using this command

> ```
> {{ dump(elements) }}
> ```

[image]

So this response is made from two arrays from which second array is not complete because it is too large. I am going to call them first [0] and second [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png) array. Also please remember that all of the values are coming dynamically into the template, which means that I need to use I can't use it like for example: elements["master"].

I have to see where values of the first array are in second array. (for example: where our_network is in second array) and to get the values for 1,2,3,4,5 ??

Please, remember that I could affect even this API response.

I am using Symfony 2.8.

I want to get the values of elements[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png) and elements[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png)[2] etc.. but only where I need it. And I need it if elements[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png)['our_network'][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png) == 1 then one behavoior, and if it is equal to elements[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png)['our_netwrok'][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeiH3.png) == 0 then other behavior.

If you have any suggestions or recommendations, let me know.

Comment: It's a bit unclear. So you want to get data from the second array by key from the first array? You wanna  do it in Twig template or php file?

Comment: I should do it in twig. That's template engine that we are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did it via PHP, not sure if you wanted if via Twig...

Use array_key_exists to see if the elements from first array exist in second array.  And two loops.  A foreach to check each element in the first array, a for loop to print out the elements values.

Here is my code:

```
$elements = array(
                array("master","Home","our_network","doesnotexist"),
                array("master"      => array("master",     0,0,0,0,0),
                      "Home"        => array("Home",       0,0,0,0,0),
                      "our_network" => array("our_network",0,0,0,0,0))
                );
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($elements);
echo "</pre>\n";

echo "<pre>\n";
foreach ($elements[0] as $section)
{
    echo "$section\n";
    if (array_key_exists($section,$elements[1]))
    {
        echo "    EXISTS!\n";
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++)
        {
            echo "        $i: " . $elements[1][$section][$i] . "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "    DOES NOT EXIST!\n";
    }
}
echo "</pre>\n";
```

The bunch of pre are just to format the output on my test Apache.  It gives you this output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => master
            [1] => Home
            [2] => our_network
            [3] => doesnotexist
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [master] => Array
                (
                    [0] => master
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                )

            [Home] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Home
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                )

            [our_network] => Array
                (
                    [0] => our_network
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                )

        )

)
master
    EXISTS!
        1: 0
        2: 0
        3: 0
        4: 0
        5: 0
Home
    EXISTS!
        1: 0
        2: 0
        3: 0
        4: 0
        5: 0
our_network
    EXISTS!
        1: 0
        2: 0
        3: 0
        4: 0
        5: 0
doesnotexist
    DOES NOT EXIST!
```

If you need to access the value for just one section, do this:

```
echo "just one section: " . $elements[1]['Home'][3] . "\n";
```

Comment: Hey Nic, thanks for the reply. I am replying from my mobile. Going to be in front of the pc in two hours.

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach ($elements[0] as $value2) 
{
    echo $value2;
    foreach($elements[$value2] as $value) 
    {

        echo $value;

    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question "*and to get the values for 1,2,3,4,5 ??*".  And $elements[$value2] does not exist since $value2 are under $elements[1].

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help. A proper explanation [would greatly improve](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions. Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.